# Upload app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I've already set all de iTunes Connect stuff(Snapshots, Description, Tags, etc...) and downloaded the Application Loader but it asks me for an .app file and I don't know how to get the .app file from my Xcode project or if I need a Certificate to do it or something please can someone help me?

Comment: .app files are Mac files. You want an .ipa file. Actually you don't need Application Loader; just archive your app, go to the archive, press Submit, and you're off to the races.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great place to look for answers to questions such as this is the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

In short, you need to:

- Ensure you have a valid App ID, or wildcard App ID set in the [Developer Member Centre](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)
- Select Product > Archive in Xcode with the project open, making sure you have "iOS Device" selected in the top left corner
- At the archive screen, you can then select Validate and (if there are no issues) Submit. The build will then appear in iTunes Connect.

The documentation linked above will guide you through this step by step.

Comment: Thanks I did it but when I validate appears this error message:
Unable to validate your application, The package does not contain an Info.plist

Comment: @FacundoSchiavoni have you ensured there is a file called Info.plist in your project somewhere? This is required. If not, the easiest thing to do would be create a new project and steal it from there, filling in the correct info.

Comment: Yes I've got 2 info.plist files

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the .ipa file, in that case:

1) Product >> Clean Build Folder

2) Change the build target from iPad/iPhone Simulator to iOS Device.

3) Under the Product menu, select Archive. This will build your application and code sign it using the Distribution (Ad Hoc or App Store). Once the build has completed the Organizer window will appear. If it does not, open it using CMD-Shift–2 or Window -> Organizer. If you see a message popup saying “codesign wants to sign using key ”privateKey“ in your keychain.”, select Allow or Always Allow.
Go to the Archives tab in Organizer and select your application, if it was not automatically selected, and choose the archive you wish to share.

4) Click the Distribute button. In the next window select that you want to upload to the app store, and click Next.
In the Code Signing Identity drop down, select the same Distribution Provisioning Profile specified in the Release configuration.
And that's pretty much the steps to upload to the App Store.